# MariaDB restore error - ERROR 1556 (HY000) at line 2562: You can't use locks with log tables

Tags: mariadb, restore, mysqldump

MariaDB Restore fails

```
mysql --host mydbhost --port 5500 --user root --password <  /var/tmp/dump.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1556 (HY000) at line 2562: You can't use locks with log tables
```

Dump created by: MySQL dump 10.15  Distrib 10.0.34-MariaDB

Source DB version: Server version       10.3.5-MariaDB-10.3.5

Answer (score 1):

Issue: The version of mysqldump is much newer than the MariaDB version used for restoration. The "Lock Table Write", feature is not available with MariaDB 10.3

Solved
Edit the dump file and remove LOCK, UNLOCK statements. Other answers suggest using `grep -v 'LOCK TABLES'`, which does not work. Not all statements in the dump file are on a single line. Use sed to remove just the lock statement text.

```
cat dump.sql | sed 's/^LOCK TABLES .* WRITE;//' | sed 's/^UNLOCK TABLES;//' | > dump_nolocks.sql
```

Comment: That's not a solution, merely a workaround. And the command is much easier: `grep -ivE "^(un)lock table" dump.sql | mysql -u root`. But I get it with same version `mysql(dump)?`.